# multiple fetchRequests cause app to freeze

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

my problem is the following: I have three buttons in my UI that will trigger the same fetch request with different parameters. If I press these button in sequence, but waiting a second or two between each, everything works fine. If I do that quicker, the app will freeze. The debugger shows me a mutex lock. Now, I am using CoreData with a mainMOC and a backgroundMOC, and I can't find what I am doing wrong and how to solve my problem.

I have checked similar questions, but all the solutions suggested didn't work for me. 
Here is the code that I believe is involved in this problem:

```
@interface LooksDataSource ()

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@end

@implementation LooksDataSource

-(id) init {
 @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"LooksDataSource exception" reason:@"please use initWithManagedObjectContext" userInfo:nil];
}

-(void) dealloc {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

-(id) initWithManagedObjectContext: (NSManagedObjectContext *) context {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.mainContext = context;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^(){
        self.backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        self.backgroundContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.mainContext.persistentStoreCoordinator;
        });        
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(repoUpdated:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:self.mainContext];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) findLooksWithPredicate: (NSPredicate *) predicate {
    if (![predicate isEqual:self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate]) {
        [self performNewRequestwithPredicate:predicate];
    }
    else {
        //return results of latest fetch
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionZeroInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][0];
        NSMutableArray *objectIDsForResults = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSManagedObject *aResult in [sectionZeroInfo objects]) {
            [objectIDsForResults addObject:aResult.objectID];
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //re-create the MOs referred to in objectIDsForResults in the "main" MOC
            NSMutableArray *resultsOnMainMOC = [NSMutableArray array];
            for (NSManagedObjectID *aResultID in objectIDsForResults) {
                [resultsOnMainMOC addObject:[self.mainContext objectWithID:aResultID]];
            }
            NSArray *results = [NSArray arrayWithArray:resultsOnMainMOC];
            [self.delegate looksDataSource:self
                       returnedResults:results];
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks all for your help

Comment: How are you using threads? Why aren't you creating a MOC specifically for the background thread that is working (not one background context which could be used by arbitrary threads)?

Comment: Wain how would I do that?

Comment: Each block you start on a background queue should create a MOC as the first thing it does. But it isn't clear how you're using threads. Do you have a reason to have multiple threads and contexts? How are you organising what runs where?

Comment: I am afraid I am not organizing the thread. The reason for multiple contexts is not locking the UI while performing long fetches

Comment: You shouldn't generally need long fetches, you would generally be using batched fetches. Perhaps you should say what your fetches / predicates are rather than trying to correct a multi thread / context solution that you may not need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Wain said, it is unclear how you are using threads here and where the background fetches are made.

That being said ...

The way you create your background MOC is not thread safe:
You create a managed object context that is using a thread confinement concurrency type.
This mean you must use this context **ONLY** on the thread that is was created on.
Since you used GCD to create this context, you don't know which thread created it nor can you keep this thread alive.

The solution to your problem is what @Wain said: For each operation you dispatch in the background, create a confined managed object context, use it and at the end of the operation make sure you dispose of it:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^(){
    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    context.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.mainContext.persistentStoreCoordinator;
    //Make the fetch and export results to main thread
});
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I tried this but then I have a problem: I need to merge changes that happen on the mainMOC in the backgroundMOC. If I don't keep a property to reference the backgroundMOC, how can I do that?

Comment: In this implementation your background MOCs are disposable. every operation "looks" at the most updated data in the store the moment it makes a fetch.

Comment: I ended up removing the background MOC and GCD altogether, and it works fine now.